# Behavior of scrollIntoViewIfNeeded

Tags: javascript, dom, js-scrollintoview

I'm working on creating a web component that, given a list of elements that are focusable, automatically has accessible keyboard navigation.

Part of that is to have the active element scrolled into view if it isn't already, and to do this i'm using the `Element.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded` (in chrome, so support shouldn't be a problem).

I'm experiencing some weird behavior, that i can't quite figure out. I've created a minimal code sandbox to show the problem.

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  const paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  paragraph.innerHTML = "element " + i;
  paragraph.tabIndex = -1;
  app.appendChild(paragraph);
}

const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowDown":
      if (app.contains(document.activeElement)) {
        const next = document.activeElement.nextElementSibling;
        next.focus();
        next.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(false);
      } else {
        const first = app.firstElementChild;
        first.focus();
        first.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(false);
      }
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      if (app.contains(document.activeElement)) {
        const previous = document.activeElement.previousElementSibling;
        previous.focus();
        previous.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(false);
      } else {
        const last = app.lastElementChild;
        last.focus();
        last.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(false);
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown, false);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app" class="app"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the `centerIfNeeded` argument doesn't seem to be respected at all. At times it is respected the first time i focus an element that is outside of the viewport, but not the second time, and sometimes it is just completely ignored.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "first call"? This method will do something only "if needed", that is, if the element is not already "into view".

Comment: I can see how that is unclear.

By first call i mean, the first time it should actually scroll something into view; the first time i focus an element that is outside of the viewport.

I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: This is a Non-standard method - `There may be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.` So i guess that whatever it actually does, it is working as expected.

Comment: @Kaiido does it work as intended for you? 

and by intended i mean scroll only the focused element into view without centering it?

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't understand that the fact it's centered IS the problem. I understood it the other way around. So, for me too the target element is centered every time the scroll happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default the `focus()` call will itself internally call `scrollIntoView()`, and the two calls will conflict.
To prevent that, you can pass the `{ preventScroll: true }` option to your calls to `focus()`.

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  const paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  paragraph.innerHTML = "element " + i;
  paragraph.tabIndex = -1;
  app.appendChild(paragraph);
}

const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowDown":
      if (app.contains(document.activeElement)) {
        const next = document.activeElement.nextElementSibling;
        next?.focus({ preventScroll: true });
        next?.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(false);
      } else {
        const first = app.firstElementChild;
        next?.focus({ preventScroll: true });
        first?.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(false);
      }
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      if (app.contains(document.activeElement)) {
        const previous = document.activeElement.previousElementSibling;
        previous?.focus({ preventScroll: true });
        previous?.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(false);
      } else {
        const last = app.lastElementChild;
        last?.focus({ preventScroll: true });
        last?.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(false);
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown, false);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app" class="app"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you!